# Using Custom ImageView items in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view

I am developing a memory game in android.

Right now I need to create a Grid of caps and I am using a custom Imageview as items in the grid.

This is my Cap Object Class that extends Imageview.

```
public class DhakkanObject extends ImageView {

public List<Fruit> fruitMap = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
public ClosedState closedState;
public OpenState openState;
public AnimationState animationState;
public State<DhakkanObject> previousState;
public State<DhakkanObject> currentState;

public DhakkanObject(Context context) {
    super(context);
    closedState = new ClosedState();
    openState = new OpenState();
    animationState = new AnimationState();
}   

public void gotoState(State<DhakkanObject> newState) {
    if (newState == null) {
        return;
    } else if (currentState == newState) {
        return;
    }
    if (currentState == null) {
        currentState = newState;
    }
    if (previousState != null)
        previousState.exit();
    previousState = currentState;
    currentState = newState;
    currentState.enter();
    invalidate();
}


public class OpenState extends State<DhakkanObject> {

    @Override
    public void enter() {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.open);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(long gameTime) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void exit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


public class ClosedState extends State<DhakkanObject>
{

    @Override
    public void enter() {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.closed);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(long gameTime) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void exit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

public class AnimationState extends State<DhakkanObject>{

    public AnimationDrawable frameByframe_animation = null;
    @Override
    public void enter() {
        setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setBackgroundResource(R.anim.dhakkan_animation);
        frameByframe_animation = (AnimationDrawable) getBackground();
        frameByframe_animation.start();
        frameByframe_animation.setOneShot(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(long gameTime) {
        post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(frameByframe_animation.isRunning()){
                    gotoState(openState);   
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void exit() {
        frameByframe_animation.stop();
        frameByframe_animation.setVisible(false, false);

    }

}

}
```

Here is my activity that Implements GridView.

```
public class DoubleBlastMainActivity extends Activity {

private Intent intent = null;
public GridView gameGrid;
public List<DhakkanObject> dhakkanList = null;
public int mLevel = 0;
public UpdateThread updateThread = null;
public DhakkanObject openDhakkan1;
public DhakkanObject openDhakkan2;
public DhakkanObject currentDhakkanClicked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.double_blast_game);

    gameGrid = ( GridView ) findViewById( R.id.dhakkanGrid );

    dhakkanList = new ArrayList<DhakkanObject>();

    createDhakkanList(2, 2);

    gameGrid.setAdapter(new DhakkanGrid( getBaseContext(), dhakkanList) );      

}

public void createDhakkanList(int numberOfCol, int numberOfRows)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < ( numberOfRows * numberOfCol ); i++)
    {
        DhakkanObject temp = new DhakkanObject(getBaseContext());
        temp.gotoState(temp.closedState);
        temp.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        dhakkanList.add(temp);
    }

    gameGrid.setNumColumns(numberOfCol);
    gameGrid.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
}


public class DhakkanGrid extends BaseAdapter 
{

    public Context context;
    public List<DhakkanObject> dhakkhanList;
    public DhakkanGrid ( Context contexttemp, List<DhakkanObject> objectlist)
    {
        this.context = contexttemp;
        dhakkanList = objectlist;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dhakkanList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dhakkanList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dhakkanList.get(position);
    }

}
}
```

The layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/game_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pauseMenu"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Moves"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dhakkanGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is a highly disproportioned grid. Meaning the image view is getting stretched in width exponentially.

[image]

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? As I cannot seem to resize the items.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `setBackgroundResource` everywhere. Use `setImageResource` instead.

Comment: I used setImageResource instead and this seems to worsen the problem. Now both height and width are getting stretched!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your problem. You should probably post an image in your description.

I would try to override the [onMeasure method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29). As explained, you can resize the ImageView. 
First use `getMeasuredWidth` and `getMeasuredHeight` to get the dimension of the ImageView. Then get the image using `getDrawable` and get the dimensions of the image.
Now, you have the correct ratio of your image, apply them to the `ImageView`.
To apply new dimensions, use the [method setMeasuredDimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMeasuredDimension%28int,%20int%29http://).

You should first decide which dimension should be resized. But I can't help you with an image of your app.

EDIT 1:
In your DhakkanObject, add this function :

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int prefWidth, int prefHeight){
   Drawable d = getDrawable();
   if(d!=null){
      int width = getMeasuredWidth(prefWidth);
      int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());

      int prefWidthView = resolveSizeAndState(width, prefWidth, 0);
      int prefHeightView = resolveSizeAndState(height, prefHeight, 0);
      setMeasuredDimension(prefWidthView, prefHeightView);
   }
   else{
      super.onMeasured(prefWidth,prefHeight);
   }
}
```

Each time your imageview is resized, the imageView checks the underlying image dimensions and expands his height to keep the correct ratio, assuming that the width is good in the first time.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the post.